# Accessing grid view row data C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, linkbutton

I am trying to set the value of a textbox to the value of a column in a gridview.  I am getting the row from a LinkButton.

The first TextBox1.Text line below works correctly to set the value of the textbox to the row number.

The second TextBox1.Text line below does nothing to my textbox.  I am expecting the value of the row(index) and column(1), but I get nothing.  There is definitely data in the gridview. The gridview is 10+ columns wide, and I have checked the value from 0-5 and get nothing in the textbox.

I am not running it with both lines uncommented out at once.

I am doing all of this to troubleshoot an issue being caused by it.

```
protected void lnkbtnPassRowData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
    if (gvr != null)
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(gvr.RowIndex.ToString());

        TextBox1.Text = GridStaffMyJobs.Rows[index].RowIndex.ToString();

        TextBox1.Text = GridStaffMyJobs.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text;
    }
}
```

Here is the code from the gridview that contains the link button.

```
<form id="StaffMyJobs" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h3>My Jobs</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblHired" runat="server" Text="Rows in green indicate jobs that have been filled." Visible="False" BorderColor="#FF0909" Font-Bold="True" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="YellowGreen"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblOffers" runat="server" Text="Rows in red indicate jobs that have pending offers." Visible="False" BorderColor="#FF0909" Font-Bold="True" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnAddJob" runat="server" Text="Add a Job" OnClick="btnAddJob_Click" Visible="true" />
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridMoreJobs" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SQLMoreJobs"  >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="more_jobs" HeaderText="more_jobs" SortExpression="more_jobs" Visible="false" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridStaffMyJobs" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns ="False" DataSourceID="SQLStaffMyJobs" ShowFooter="True" OnRowDataBound="GridMoreJobs_RowDataBound" HorizontalAlign="Center"  >
            <Columns>


    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnPassRowData"  Text='Reopen' 
            runat="server" 
            OnClick="lnkbtnPassRowData_Click"  Visible='<%# 
            CanReopen((object)Eval("student_hired")) %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

</form>
```

Here is a screenshot of executing the page and letting the line run that puts the index of the row in the textbox.
[image]

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your second line and inspect the value of `GridStaffMyJobs.Rows[index].Cells`. Collections are zero-based; are you sure you want `Cells[1]` and not `Cells[0]`? If so, inspect `Cells[1].Text`; you haven't shown anything setting that.

Comment: The gridview is 10+ columns wide, and I have checked the value from 0-5 and get nothing in the textbox

Comment: Can you add your gridview code from the .aspx file to the post?

Comment: I added the template field code.

Comment: I am almost certain that I am not actually accessing the data from the cells.

Comment: I was able to bind the JobID field to a CommandArgument and get the value like that.